# Rails / radio button with images in labels and options disabled

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, radio-button, simple-form

Rails 4. I'm trying to create a radio button

1) with text plus image in label

2) with options can be (or not) disabled

I can solve 1) with a `f.collection_radio_buttons` and 2) with `f.input`...but I can't find solution solving 2 points...

There is a solution using only simple form helper ? (without js/Jquery)

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll try to answer myself :

This code solve the 2 points :

```
 <%= f.collection_radio_buttons( :typepayment, 
                                 [[0,t(:radio_button_type_payment_None)], [1,t(:radio_button_type_payment_DirectDebit)], [2,t(:radio_button_type_payment_CreditCard)]],
                                 :first,
                                 :last,
                                 item_wrapper_tag: :div
                               ) do |b|
                                   b.label {  (condition_is_disabled ? b.radio_button(disabled: "\"disabled\"") : b.radio_button) + " "+
                                             (b.value == 0 ? t(:radio_button_type_payment_None) : (b.value == 1 ? t(:radio_button_type_payment_DirectDebit) : t(:radio_button_type_payment_CreditCard) )) +
                                             (b.value != 0 ? image_tag("typepayment_#{b.value}.png", class: "img_type_payment") : "") }
                                 end

 %>
```

The block code given to `collection_radio_buttons` is here to construct labee with images.

`disabled: "\"disabled\""` : I didn't found other method to pass the `disabled` state to the helper

If someone have a better answer, it's welcome :)